# Merging the two array of arrays based on a field value

Tags: php

There are two arrays of arrays. $user and $experience are two arrays and i want to achieve $final as my expected output.

I have two arrays:

```
$user = [
  [
    "country" => "aus",
    "new_experiences" => 0,
    "new_users" => 6
  ],
  [
    "country" => "jpn",
    "new_experiences" => 0,
    "new_users" => 5
  ]
];

$experience = [
  [
    "country" => "jpn",
    "new_experiences" => 12,
    "new_users" => 0
  ],
  [
    "country" => "usa",
    "new_experiences" => 10,
    "new_users" => 0
  ]
];
```

After merging these two arrays based on country, how can i get:

```
$final = [
  [
    "country" => "aus",
    "new_experiences" => 0,
    "new_users" => 6
  ],
  [
    "country" => "jpn",
    "new_experiences" => 12,
    "new_users" => 5
  ],
  [
    "country" => "usa",
    "new_experiences" => 10,
    "new_users" => 0
  ]
];
```

Comment: Have you got the solution of your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your GOal using this simple steps:

- Iterate and arrange your array into a single array using foreach
- Create a key-value array, just like I have created `$issetArray`
- Push all the value in a $final array, you will get the desired output

I have created a simple logic using `foreach` loop, `isset()` and `array_push()`

```
$user = array(
  array(
    "country" => "aus",
    "new_experiences" => 0,
    "new_users" => 6
  ),
  array(
    "country" => "jpn",
    "new_experiences" => 0,
    "new_users" => 5
  )
);

$experience = array(
  array(
    "country" => "jpn",
    "new_experiences" => 12,
    "new_users" => 0
  ),
  array(
    "country" => "usa",
    "new_experiences" => 10,
    "new_users" => 0
  )
);

$final = array();
$issetArray = array();

foreach($user as $key => $value)
{
    if(isset($issetArray[$value['country']]))
    {
        $issetArray[$value['country']]['new_experiences'] = $value;
        $issetArray[$value['country']]['new_users'] = $value;
    }
    else
    {
        $issetArray[$value['country']] = $value; 
    }
}

foreach($experience as $key => $value)
{
    if(isset($issetArray[$value['country']]))
    {
        $issetArray[$value['country']]['new_experiences'] = $value['new_experiences'];
        $issetArray[$value['country']]['new_users'] = $value['new_users'];
    }
    else
    {
        $issetArray[$value['country']] = $value; 
    }
}

foreach($issetArray as $value)
{
    array_push($final, $value);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($final);
```

Click on the link to know more about [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
array_unique(array_merge($array1,$array2), SORT_REGULAR);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Please check the final output, You answer not satisfying that.